# Loading Comments From a Class?

Tags: comments, oop

I am not using the function `comments_template()`. Instead I am trying to load the comments from a Class. There is no `comments.php` file on the root.

### Comment Class

```
namespace Core\Views;

class Comments{

    public function render(){
        $this->_comments();
        $this->_form();
    }

    private function _comments(){
        echo $this->_get_comments();
    }

    private function _get_comments(){

        global $post;
        ob_start(); ?>


        <a name="#comment"></a>

        <?php if ( get_comments_number() == 0 && 'closed' == $post->comment_status ):

        else: ?>

            <div class="comments_form_title">
                <strong><?php comments_number('No response yet on', '1 response to', '% responses to'); ?></strong> <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;

        if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
            <ul id="comment-list" class="media-list">
                <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&avatar_size=60&callback=kitten_list_comments'); ?>
            </ul>

            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
            </div>

        <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>
            <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
                <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->
            <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
                <!-- If comments are closed. -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif;

        $html = ob_get_clean();
        return $html;

    }
    private function _form(){
        echo $this->_get_form();
    }

    private function  _get_form(){
        global $post, $current_user;

        ob_start(); ?>


            <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
                <div id="respond">
                    <h4>Leave a comment</h4>
                    <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
                        <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
                    </div>

            <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$current_user->ID ) : ?>
                <p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p></div>
            <?php else : ?>

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

                    <?php if ( $current_user->ID ) : ?>
                        <p><?php _e("Logged in as", 'ogr'); ?> <a href="<?php echo admin_url('profile.php') ?>">
                                <?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account"><?php _e("Log out", 'ogr'); ?> &raquo;</a></p>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-3">Your Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input required="required" type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="form-control" size="40" value="" name="your-name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-3">Your Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input required="required" type="email" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="form-control" size="40" value="" name="your-email">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-3">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <textarea required="required" aria-invalid="false" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="40" name="your-message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9"><input type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary" value="Send Message"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://demo1.developerpage.net/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
                    </div>

                </form>

                </div>
        <?php

            endif; endif;

                $html = ob_get_clean();
            return $html;
        }
}
```

### Problems:

1. `have_comments()` is `false` while the post have comments.
2. `wp_list_comments()` also not printing comments.

Here is the [`$wp_query` object](https://gist.github.com/prionkor/dbad37e5cc4eb3e3e154) if you need to take a look.

Here is how I am calling the class (again, very basic):

```
 $comments = new Comments;
 $comments->render();
```